# How do I keep the second of two navbars at the top once you start scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navbar which has two separate sections for the contact info and the menu itself. When I scroll down, I want the contact info to disappear normally, but the menu to stick at the top of the page, until I scroll back to the top when the menu is pushed back down by the contact info. Any help appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  /* position: fixed; */
}


/*NAVBAR-CONTACT*/

.navbar-contact {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(242, 122, 61, 1);
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-contact li {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  float: right;
}

.navbar-contact li:first-child {
  padding-right: 25%;
}

.navbar-contact li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-contact li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*NAVBAR-MENU*/

.navbar-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 16px;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 60px 0 60px;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-contact">
      <li><a href="#">info@domain.co.uk</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">(XXX) XXXX XXXX</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hint: `position: sticky`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is in css is to use position: sticky;

Here's an example from w3schools ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp ):

```
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Edit: Sticky elements are sticky relative to their parent element. Your navbar-menu is inside of your nav element, so it will only be visible as long as your nav is in the screen. You should be able to keep your styling pretty much the same, just move your navbar-menu outside of your nav element, like this:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-contact">
        <li><a href="#">info@domain.co.uk</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">(XXX) XXXX XXXX</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul class="navbar-menu" style="position: sticky;">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then just add the above css to your navbar-menu, like this:

```
/*NAVBAR-MENU*/

.navbar-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

( Note that I removed position: fixed; )

Comment: Where do I add that in?

I've tried putting it in the navbar-menu class but that doesn't seem to work.

`
.navbar-menu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.8);
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    /* position: fixed; */
    width:100%;
    position: sticky;
    position:-webkit-sticky ;
    top: 0;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try javascript.
I copy your code and try with this w3schools resource...try this:

```
<script>
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }

</script>
```

then add some css to your #navbar:

```
#navbar{
width: 100%;
top: 0;
transition: top 0.3s;
position: fixed;}
```

Here to find out more about it: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp